# Как получить данные в объекте, массиве в handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Например this это объект. У него массив teams, в нем объект со строкой name.
Как обратиться к нему? Нужно создавать переменную?

```
        '<div>',
            '{{ this.teams[0].name }}</span>',
         '</div>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращаться нужно будет так:

```
this.teams.0.name
```

Где `0` индекс массива